# LoadError: cannot load such file -- gherkin/formatter/json_formatter , on running command rackup ,ruby version 2.2.0 and cucumber 2.1.0

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cucumber, gherkin

I am getting LoadError: cannot load such file -- gherkin/formatter/json_formatter , on running command rackup ,

ruby version 2.2.0
cucumber 2.1.0
os :ubuntu 15.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is coming since you are using the newer version of gherkin gem where path for the gherkin formatter is changed .
,please install the compatible gherkin version as required in your app.